# Getting only 100mbps behind gigabit switch

Tags: networking, switch, wired-networking

I'm having issues with my internet speed at home. It should easily have over 700mbps download/upload. First I'll give you an overview of my setup.

ISP modem > Switch (TP Link TL-SG116) > My laptop (and other devices).
All UTP sockets from my house are connected with cat6a cable to the switch.
The switch is connected with a cat 6a cable to the modem.
My laptop is connected with a cat 6 cable to the socket in the wall.

When I'm using my docking station (uses Realtek USB GbE Family Controller)  from my laptop I'm only getting 100mbps from the switch, even when I selected 1Gbps full duplex. When I bypass the switch (I connect the wall cable directly to the modem, i'm getting 1Gbps). When I'm using my laptops built-in ethernet port (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V) connected to the switch, it works fine (I'm getting gigabit speed)

When I test every port on the switch with a random UTP cable with my laptops NIC, it works fine. So I don't think the switch is the problem.

[My TP-Link TL-SG116 switch with my in-wall cables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ert6G.png)

Comment: Are you connecting using USB2 by any chance? And have you confirmed the USB Dock is capable of a 1Gbps connection? Also try different USB cable.

Comment: The docking station is a usb-c. It also powers the laptop. It is capable of 1G because when I connect the wall cable (that points to the laptop) directly to the modem, I'm getting 1G. I looks like the docking station cannot cope with the switch